# Which chapter of the manga does the last season of Attack on Titan anime start in?

Tags: attack-on-titan

The last anime season of Attack on Titan anime started. If I want to get spoilers of the story and read the manga chapters from that point on, which chapter of the manga do I have to start in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest episode (now Season 4, Episode 1) has covered Chapters 91-92.